# How to print the outcome of this code in HTML with proc print command

Tags: sas

How can I make the outcome of this code to print into html using `proc print`? This is because I have to integrate the code inside an existing code that uses only `proc print`. Thanks in advance.

```
filename cmd pipe "dir G:\ | findstr /c:""bytes free""";

data _null_;
   infile cmd;
   input;
   free_space_gb = input(scan(_infile_,3,' '), comma20.) * 2**-30;
   put "There is currently " free_space_gb 8.2 "GB of free space on the G 
   drive";
call symput('free_space_gb',free_space_gb); /*Create macro variable*/
run;

%macro print_alert_html;
  %if &free_space_gb < 1 %then %do;
   ods listing close;
   ods html file = "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\report.html";
    ods html text = "Alert: only &free_space_gb GB of space left on the G 
drive!";
   ods html close;
   ods listing;
 %end;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use Proc PRINT then the Gb information needs to be kept in a data set.  You might want to use Proc REPORT  when outputting a status message because it has a NOHEADER option.

The REPORT where clause will cause output only when the Gb is < 1.

```
filename cmd pipe "dir G:\ | findstr /c:""bytes free""";

data message;
   infile cmd;
   input;

   free_space_gb = input(scan(_infile_,3,' '), comma20.) * 2**-30;

   message = "There is currently " || strip(put(free_space_gb, 8.2)) ||  "GB of free space on the G drive";
run;

%macro print_alert_html;
   ods listing close;
   ods html file = "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\report.html";

   title;
   footnote;
   options nocenter nodate nonumber;
   proc report data=message noheader;
      column message;
      where free_space_gb < 1.00;
   run;

   ods html close;
   ods listing;
%mend;

%print_alert_html;
```

Comment: So if I add in the end this proc print data=message;
run; it should work?

Comment: Code posted worked for me. The Proc REPORT is in place of Proc PRINT.  The 'tabular' output of either procedure will go into the html file.  Compared to PRINT, REPORT has a little more control over what is or is not shown in the output.  Try replacing REPORT with the Proc PRINT.  The 'tabular' output will show an OBS column and the GB and MESSAGE column. The will also be column headers.  Thus, PRINT has a bit of extraneous output for a simple status message.  ODS TEXT can end up not being rendered if there is no procedural output sent to the ODS target -- you might have been experiencing that.

Comment: @Tazz it's faster to test it than to ask if it works. If you tried it and it doesn't work then include more details.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot find out if it works because there is much more than 1GB space in the disk! However, I think it works so far, I will test other methods too to be more sure! Thanks :)

Comment: You can always change the threshold value from < 1.0 to a larger one, say < 2000  that will incur the warning. One you are satisfied reduce it again.